# Slow running query of view

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-administration

I have a view that summarizes calendar specific data, it is constantly showing performance issues and creating help desk tickets from customers.

We had a DBA on staff for a short time but he never showed up to work so was let go. This has largely been a developer managed database. I have run Brent Ozar's Sps (sp_BlitzFirst) and the queries to this view constantly have the highest cost.

Query Plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ry8Lo6T74

view code

```
SELECT 
rae.ResourceAvailabilityExceptEventId AS MasterEventEntityId,
me.MasterEventId AS MasterEventId,     
null AS ParentEventId,
me.MasterEventBillingInfoId AS MasterEventBillingInfoId,
0 AS HasScheduledParentEvent,
me.Subject AS EventSubject,
me.Description AS EventDescription,
me.EventStartDate AS EventStartDate,
me.EventEndDate AS EventEndDate,
me.TimeZone AS TimeZone,
mebi.TotalBillAmount  AS BillAmount,
null AS CancelledReason,
null AS HasDiagnosis,
null  AS ParticipantAuthorizationId,
null  AS AuthorizationNumber,
null  AS AuthorizationDescription,
null  AS BillingSourceName,
null  AS BillingSourceTypeId,
me.EventTypeId      AS EventTypeId,
cet.Description      AS EventType,
me.EventSubTypeId    AS EventSubTypeId,
cest.Description    AS EventSubType,
1    AS IsTimeOff,
0    AS IsInsurance,
CASE WHEN me.MasterEventBillingInfoId is null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IsBillable,
0    AS IsScheduled,
0    AS IsCompleted,
0    AS IsRecurring,
0    AS IsLinkedEvent,
null  AS ChildEventTypeId,
null  AS ChildEventType,
'timeoff'        AS EventStatus,
null  AS EventStatusId,
null  AS WorkflowStatusId,
null  AS WorkflowStatusDescription,
ra.LinkId        AS LinkId,
ra.EntityId        AS EntityId,
IIF(ra.EntityId = 'E32955F7-1CE8-46A1-98D3-06A69FA4B29E',1,0) AS IsAssignedParticipant,
IIF(ra.EntityId = '173F0473-747A-48F6-B7E8-06948370AAF8',1,0) AS IsAssignedEmployee,
par.PersonId      AS ParticipantId, 
emp.PersonId      AS AssignedEmployeeId,
null  AS BillUnderEmployeeId,
null  AS SupervisorEmployeeId,
par.FirstName      AS ParticipantFirstName,
par.LastName      AS ParticipantLastName,
emp.FirstName      AS AssignedEmployeeFirstName,
emp.LastName      AS AssignedEmployeeLastName,
null  AS BillUnderEmployeeFirstName,
null  AS BillUnderEmployeeLastName,
null  AS SupervisorEmployeeFirstName,
null  AS SupervisorEmployeeLastName,
null  AS CredentialId,
null  AS CredentialName,
me.LocationId      AS LocationId,
o.Name  AS Location,
0    AS PublishedScoreSheetCount,
0    AS SessionCount,
0    AS AuthItemCount,
null  AS BillCodes,
pstat.Description    AS PayrollStatus,
me.PayrollStatusId    AS PayrollStatusId,
me.PayrollLastExportDate    AS PayrollLastExportDate,
me.PayCodeId      AS PayCodeId,
pc.Name  AS PayCodeName
FROM Data.MasterEvent me
JOIN Data.ResourceAvailabilityExceptEvent rae WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON me.MasterEventId = rae.ResourceAvailabilityExceptEventId
JOIN Data.ResourceAvailability ra WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON rae.ResourceAvailabilityId = ra.ResourceAvailabilityId AND ra.IsSoftDeleted = 0
JOIN Mgr.Code cet WITH ( NOLOCK ) on cet.CodeId = me.EventTypeId
LEFT JOIN Mgr.Code cest WITH ( NOLOCK ) on cest.CodeId = me.EventSubTypeId
LEFT JOIN Data.MasterEventBillingInfo mebi WITH ( NOLOCK ) on me.MasterEventBillingInfoId = mebi.MasterEventBillingInfoId
LEFT JOIN Data.Person emp WITH ( NOLOCK ) on ra.LinkId = emp.PersonId AND ra.EntityId = '173F0473-747A-48F6-B7E8-06948370AAF8'
LEFT JOIN Data.Person par WITH ( NOLOCK ) on ra.LinkId = par.PersonId AND ra.EntityId = 'E32955F7-1CE8-46A1-98D3-06A69FA4B29E'
LEFT JOIN Data.Organization o WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON o.OrganizationId = me.LocationId AND o.IsSoftDeleted = 0
LEFT JOIN Mgr.Code pstat WITH ( NOLOCK ) on pstat.CodeId = me.PayrollStatusId
LEFT JOIN Data.PayCode pc  WITH(NOLOCK) on pc.PayCodeId = me.PayCodeId
WHERE me.IsSoftDeleted = 0

UNION

SELECT 
mee.MasterEventEntityId,
mee.MasterEventId,     
me.ParentEventId,
me.MasterEventBillingInfoId,
CASE WHEN separent.ScheduledEventId is null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as HasScheduledParentEvent,
me.Subject as EventSubject,
me.Description as EventDescription,
me.EventStartDate,
me.EventEndDate,
me.TimeZone,
mebi.TotalBillAmount  AS BillAmount,
COALESCE(se.CancelledReason,sece.CancelledReason,null) AS CancelledReason,
IIF(egb.DiagnosisCodes IS NOT NULL,1,0) AS HasDiagnosis,
mebi.ParticipantAuthorizationId,
auth.AuthorizationNumber,
auth.Description as AuthorizationDescription,
billsrccmp.Name as BillingSourceName,
billsrc.BillingSourceTypeId,
me.EventTypeId,
cet.Description as EventType,
me.EventSubTypeId,
cest.Description as EventSubType,
0    AS IsTimeOff,
CASE 
  WHEN billsrc.BillingSourceTypeId = 'CCBDBCFC-2225-4511-B617-190430D1897C' THEN 1 
  else 0 END as IsInsurance,
CASE WHEN me.MasterEventBillingInfoId is null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as IsBillable,
CASE WHEN se.ScheduledEventId is null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as IsScheduled,
CASE WHEN ce.CompletedEventId is null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as IsCompleted,
CASE WHEN se.ScheduleRecurrenceId is null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as IsRecurring,
IIF(meparent.EventTypeId = '7d881908-d373-43eb-a550-ca5e6b55137c', 0, 1) IsLinkedEvent,

pevstat.EventTypeId as ChildEventTypeId,
pevstat.EventType as ChildEventType,

COALESCE(pevstat.EventStatus, evstat.EventStatus) as EventStatus,

ce.EventStatusId,
ce.WorkflowStatusId,
ceC.Description,
mee.LinkId,
mee.EntityId,
IIF(mee.LinkId = par.ParticipantId, 1, 0) as IsAssignedParticipant,
IIF(mee.LinkId = me.AssignedEmployeeId, 1, 0) as IsAssignedEmployee,
par.ParticipantId,
aemp.EmployeeId as AssignedEmployeeId,
buemp.EmployeeId as BillUnderEmployeeId,
semp.EmployeeId as SupervisorEmployeeId,
pperson.FirstName as ParticipantFirstName,
pperson.LastName as ParticipantLastName,
aeperson.FirstName as AssignedEmployeeFirstName,
aeperson.LastName as AssignedEmployeeLastName,
bueperson.FirstName as BillUnderEmployeeFirstName,
bueperson.LastName as BillUnderEmployeeLastName,
seperson.FirstName as SupervisorEmployeeFirstName,
seperson.LastName as SupervisorEmployeeLastName,
c.CredentialId,
c.Name as CredentialName,
me.LocationId,
o.Name AS Location,
COALESCE(sss.ScheduledScoreSheetCount, css.CompletedScoreSheetCount, 0) as PublishedScoreSheetCount,
COALESCE(sss.ScheduledSessionCount, css.CompletedSessionCount, 0) as SessionCount,
aai.ApptAuthItemCount as AuthItemCount,    
bc.BillCodes,
pstat.Description as PayrollStatus,
me.PayrollStatusId,
me.PayrollLastExportDate,
pc.PayCodeId,
pc.Name AS PayCodeName
FROM Data.MasterEventEntity mee WITH ( NOLOCK )
JOIN Data.MasterEvent me WITH ( NOLOCK ) on mee.MasterEventId = me.MasterEventId AND me.IsSoftDeleted = 0
JOIN Views.EventStatus evstat on evstat.MasterEventId = me.MasterEventId
LEFT JOIN Data.Organization o WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON o.OrganizationId = me.LocationId AND o.IsSoftDeleted = 0
LEFT JOIN Views.EventGroupingBase egb on egb.MasterEventId = mee.MasterEventId
LEFT JOIN Data.ScheduledEvent se WITH ( NOLOCK ) on se.ScheduledEventId = me.MasterEventId
LEFT JOIN Data.CompletedEvent ce WITH ( NOLOCK ) on ce.CompletedEventId = me.MasterEventId
LEFT JOIN Mgr.Code ceC WITH ( NOLOCK ) on ce.WorkflowStatusId = ceC.CodeId
LEFT JOIN Data.ScheduledEvent sece WITH ( NOLOCK ) on sece.ScheduledEventId = ce.ScheduledEventId
JOIN Mgr.Code cet WITH ( NOLOCK ) on cet.CodeId = me.EventTypeId
LEFT JOIN Mgr.Code cest WITH ( NOLOCK ) on cest.CodeId = me.EventSubTypeId
LEFT JOIN Data.MasterEvent meparent WITH ( NOLOCK ) on meparent.MasterEventId = me.ParentEventId
LEFT JOIN Data.ScheduledEvent separent WITH ( NOLOCK ) on separent.ScheduledEventId = me.ParentEventId
LEFT JOIN Views.ParentEventStatus pevstat on me.EventTypeId = '7d881908-d373-43eb-a550-ca5e6b55137c' AND pevstat.MasterEventId = me.MasterEventId
LEFT JOIN Data.MasterEventBillingInfo mebi WITH ( NOLOCK ) on mebi.MasterEventBillingInfoId = me.MasterEventBillingInfoId and mebi.IsSoftDeleted = 0
LEFT JOIN Mgr.Code pstat WITH ( NOLOCK ) on pstat.CodeId = me.PayrollStatusId
LEFT JOIN Data.PayCode pc  WITH(NOLOCK) on pc.PayCodeId=me.PayCodeId
LEFT JOIN Data.Participant par WITH ( NOLOCK ) on par.ParticipantId = COALESCE(mebi.ParticipantId, mee.LinkId)
LEFT JOIN Data.Person pperson WITH ( NOLOCK ) on pperson.PersonId = par.ParticipantId and pperson.IsSoftDeleted = 0
LEFT JOIN Data.Employee buemp WITH ( NOLOCK ) on buemp.EmployeeId = mebi.BillUnderEmployeeId
LEFT JOIN Data.Person bueperson WITH ( NOLOCK ) on bueperson.PersonId = buemp.EmployeeId and bueperson.IsSoftDeleted = 0
LEFT JOIN Data.Employee aemp WITH ( NOLOCK ) on aemp.EmployeeId = me.AssignedEmployeeId
LEFT JOIN Data.Person aeperson WITH ( NOLOCK ) on aeperson.PersonId = aemp.EmployeeId and aeperson.IsSoftDeleted = 0
LEFT JOIN Data.Credential c WITH ( NOLOCK ) on c.CredentialId = mebi.CredentialId and c.IsSoftDeleted = 0
LEFT JOIN Data.Employee semp WITH ( NOLOCK ) on semp.EmployeeId = mebi.SupervisorEmployeeId
LEFT JOIN Data.Person seperson WITH ( NOLOCK ) on seperson.PersonId = semp.EmployeeId and seperson.IsSoftDeleted = 0
LEFT JOIN Data.ParticipantAuthorization auth WITH ( NOLOCK ) on auth.ParticipantAuthorizationId = mebi.ParticipantAuthorizationId and auth.IsSoftDeleted = 0
LEFT JOIN Data.Contract authContract WITH ( NOLOCK ) on authContract.ContractId = auth.ContractId and authContract.IsSoftDeleted = 0
LEFT JOIN Data.BillingSource billsrc WITH ( NOLOCK ) on billsrc.BillingSourceId = authContract.BillingSourceId
LEFT JOIN Data.Company billsrccmp WITH ( NOLOCK ) on billsrccmp.CompanyId = billsrc.BillingSourceId and billsrccmp.IsSoftDeleted = 0
LEFT JOIN Data.InvoiceCharge ic WITH ( NOLOCK ) on ic.CompletedEventId = me.MasterEventId and ic.InvoiceChargeStatusId != 'A2D34290-8630-4735-ACCF-E08D3D1A9480' and ic.IsSoftDeleted = 0
LEFT JOIN Data.Invoice inv WITH ( NOLOCK ) on ic.InvoiceId = inv.InvoiceId and inv.IsSoftDeleted = 0
LEFT JOIN (SELECT
MasterEventBillingInfoId,
count(AuthorizationItemId) ApptAuthItemCount
FROM Data.MasterEventBillingInfoAuthItem mebiai WITH ( NOLOCK )
WHERE mebiai.IsSoftDeleted = 0
GROUP BY mebiai.MasterEventBillingInfoId) aai ON aai.MasterEventBillingInfoId = mebi.MasterEventBillingInfoId
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT
mbi2.MasterEventBillingInfoId,
STUFF((
SELECT ',' + CONCAT(bc.Name,
IIF(caeai.Modifier1 != '', CONCAT('-', caeai.Modifier1), ''),
IIF(caeai.Modifier2 != '', CONCAT(' ', caeai.Modifier2), ''),
IIF(caeai.Modifier3 != '', CONCAT(' ', caeai.Modifier3), ''),
IIF(caeai.Modifier4 != '', CONCAT(' ', caeai.Modifier4), ''))
FROM Data.MasterEventBillingInfoAuthItem caeai WITH ( NOLOCK ) 
JOIN Data.AuthorizationItem ai WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON caeai.AuthorizationItemId = ai.AuthorizationItemId AND ai.IsSoftDeleted = 0
JOIN Data.FeeScheduleItem fsi WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON ai.FeeScheduleItemId = fsi.FeeScheduleItemId AND fsi.IsSoftDeleted = 0
JOIN Data.BillCode bc WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON bc.BillCodeId = fsi.BillCodeId AND bc.IsSoftDeleted = 0
WHERE mbi2.MasterEventBillingInfoId = caeai.MasterEventBillingInfoId AND caeai.IsSoftDeleted = 0
ORDER BY bc.Name
FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') AS BillCodes
FROM Data.MasterEventBillingInfo mbi2 WITH ( NOLOCK ) 
) bc ON bc.MasterEventBillingInfoId = mebi.MasterEventBillingInfoId
LEFT JOIN (SELECT
s.ScheduledEventId,
count(s.ScoreSheetId) ScheduledScoreSheetCount,
count(SessionId) ScheduledSessionCount
FROM Data.ScheduledEventScoreSheet s WITH ( NOLOCK ) 
left join Data.DataSheet ds on s.ScoreSheetId = ds.DataSheetId
WHERE s.IsSoftDeleted = 0 AND ds.DefinitionFinishedDate IS NOT NULL AND ds.CompletionDate IS NULL
GROUP BY s.ScheduledEventId) sss ON sss.ScheduledEventId = me.MasterEventId
LEFT JOIN (SELECT
s.CompletedEventId,
count(ScoreSheetId) CompletedScoreSheetCount,
count(SessionId) CompletedSessionCount
FROM Data.CompletedEventScoreSheet s WITH ( NOLOCK )
WHERE s.IsSoftDeleted = 0
GROUP BY s.CompletedEventId) css ON css.CompletedEventId = me.MasterEventId        
WHERE mee.ShowOnCalendar = 1 AND mee.IsSoftDeleted = 0
```

I need some direction on what I can do, even if it is just recommendations on some good reliable DBA consultants I can bring in.

Comment: Is the UNION removal of duplicate rows needed? Otherwise try UNION ALL.

Comment: I think that PasteThePlan link just broke my browser. Do you have a plain text explain plan you can put in the story (and keep the link as a nice extra).

Comment: @jarlh SQL Server 2014

Comment: @GolezTrol XML is too large to add to the ticket

Comment: It's a thing of beauty, to be sure -- [`WITH (NOLOCK)` everywhere](https://blogs.sentryone.com/AaronBertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/), needlessly obtuse table aliases, a callous disregard for formatting and liberal sprinkling of magic GUIDs without comments to explain what they mean. Aside from `UNION`/`UNION ALL`, you may want to use the Database Engine Tuning Advisor to tell you about possibly missing indexes. You need to be careful about implementing its advice unthinkingly (it tends to suggest too much) but for an involuntary DBA it's better than nothing.

Comment: The sheer complexity of this view with its subqueries and groupings make me think that some smaller tables are struggling to get out, possibly ones maintained independently or with triggers to offer an alternative fast view of queried data (indexes on computed columns are better, but the stuff this view is doing doesn't much lend itself to that). Unfortunately, implementing something like that without breaking the existing stuff or tanking performance is not trivial. Even so, you could consider periodically "dumping" this whole view in a separate DB and redirecting non-real time readers to it.

Comment: I am pretty sure that by the biggest performance black hole here is that you have a view that joins to tons of other views. Nested views are the spawn of the devil. They seem to logical but totally destroy any ability to generate even a reasonable execution plan. Grant Fritchey has a great discussion on how bad that really is. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/#seven

Comment: @JeroenMostert The formatting is a result of pasting into Stack, I removed the comments we had to preserve size.

Comment: Then I take back what I said except the `NOLOCK`, which seems like a bad thing to have in a view that looks like it's supposed to serve up transactionally consistent data. But that's not a performance issue. :-) (Snapshot isolation is still something to consider.)

Comment: As @jarlh mentioned, UNION  results to 41% of the cost according to query plan and seems like it is the biggest contributor to a slow performance, therefore consider to replace it with UNION ALL, if possible by logic

Comment: I will guess that your code uses that really complex view too much. There are likely points (perhaps many) when your system just needs some basic subset of information generated by that view and not all of the lengthy, complicated detail that it computes. I can't imagine that the string of billcodes changes much so it may help to materialize that concatentation.

Answer (score 0):

It might be not the only one big problem, but it looks like you have Key Lookup for 7K values in MasterEventBillingInfoAuthItem table and 300 Lookups in MasterEvent table. Review indexing on these tables.